# Is there any method to setstate using location.state.map value in reactJs?

Tags: reactjs

In this code i want the values of location.state.map i.e {val.img},{val.price} etc to be set below mention useStates.
I actually wanted to send the values of location.state.map in the bucket of my ecommerce webapp just like a normal shopping cart.

```
export default function DetailsPage(props) {
  let location = useLocation();
  let navigate = useNavigate();
```

In the code below i want to set the value of setPic with {val.img} (you can find this in below code ). Similarly i want to set the value of setPrice with {val.price} and so on.

```
  const [vpic,setPic]=useState();
  const [vquant,setQuant]=useState();
  const [vprice,setPrice]=useState("2345");
  const [vdetailname,setDetailname]=useState();
  
 
  const [bucketData, setbucketData] = useState([
    {
      pic: vpic,
      quant: vquant,
      price: vprice,
      detailname:vdetailname
    }
  ]);

  const addToCart =()=>{
         navigate("/home/bucket", { state: bucketData });

  }
  return (   
                   <div>
```

This is from where i want the values into the useState.

```
            {location.state.map((val, index) => {
              
                      return (
                                <div className="background" style= 
                 {{textAlign:"left",backgroundColor:"transparent"}}>   
                                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                                      <Container>
                                  <table style={{width:"100%"}}>
                                      <tr >
                                        <td>
```

For example I want the value of src={val.img} to be set into setPic useState.

```
                                        <img
                                        id="image"
                                    src={val.img}
                                    style={{border:"1px dotted black"}}
                                    />  
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                        <h5 id="name">{val.name}</h5>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <p>
                                        <strong style={{padding:"5px"}}>Quantity</strong> <br/>
                                        <input type="number" id="quantity" min="1" max="10" placeholder="1" 
                                        // onChange={e => setQuant(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                        </p>
                                    <hr/>
                                        <p id="prodprice"><strong>{val.price}</strong></p>
                                    <hr/>
                                    <button onClick={addToCart({val.img},)} style={{backgroundColor:"yellow",fontWeight:"bold",padding:"3px"}}>Add To Cart</button>
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </Container>
                              );               
                    </div>           
                  );
      })}      
   </div>    
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Can you add additional details?

Comment: Please include more details

Comment: I had added the clarification now please check it

Comment: Hi Beren. I agree, it isn't quite clear what you want other than at some point you want *something* from the `location.state` mapping to go into component state. You are mapping an array so which array element's fields should be stored in state? Are you really wanting to store the route state into component state?

Comment: Yeah, actually i am making a makeup product webapp in which there are lot of products and if the user click any of the product it will redirect it to the detailed page of that specific product. The above code is of that detailedproduct in which user can see the product name product price, adjust product quantity and then place the order. So if the user click on the addtocart button whatever specification of the product was their should be sent to the user's cart ..

Comment: And the thing you specified as _something_ is basically the product name , product price, product image, and product quantity which i am mapping through the `location.state`. After this i am unable to send that products specification to the user bucket . If you had any other option for this scenario then kindly share, it would be helpful

Comment: `location.state` is obviously an array, but are you mapping more than a single item? Sounds like you simply want a handler on each item mapped that updates the `bucketData` state array.

Comment: No i am mapping a single item here

Comment: If there is any other solution for this kindly share that please